# What's the preferred way to validate data for a row in DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, validation, dbix-class

I need to validate incoming data in several controllers of a web app before storing in a DB ([`DBIx::Class`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass)). Basically, I need to validate the value for each column using a callback (anonymous sub). I initially thought about using [`Params::Validate`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Params%3a%3aValidate) in each controller. But this approach has two problems:

1. There's no easy way to handle validation errors with
   `Params::Validate`, as it simply dies on the first invalid param with an error string.
2. I have to duplicate the validation logic for every column in all the controllers, which
       violates the DRY principle.

I think the best way would be to make the validation logic part of the model. What's the prefered way to do this in [`DBIx::Class`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add validation callbacks to the columns metadata use `add_columns` in the Result class, e.g.

```
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
    '+mycolumn' => {
        validate => sub {
            my ($schema, $val) = @_;
            # validate $val, possibly using $schema
        },
    },
    ...
);
```

To facilitate the use of these callbacks, you can create a [DBIx::Class сomponent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aManual%3a%3aComponent).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what and how exactly you want to validate your data, but did you try to use [DBIx::Class::Validation](http://search.cpan.org/~claco/DBIx-Class-Validation-0.02005/lib/DBIx/Class/Validation.pm) for your needs? It should fit.